# python list index out of range isinstance()

Tags: python

Getting a IndexError: List out of range when I run:

```
duplicates([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

When I run in shell:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list = ['blah', 1, 2, 3]

if (isinstance(list[0], str)):
    list.append(list[0])
    list.pop(0)
```

Everything works fine.

```
def duplicates(array):
    list = []
    for i in array:
        if (array.count(i) > 1): 
            if (list.count(i) < 1):
                list.append(i)
            else: pass

    # has nothing to do with problem statement. Test cases are requiring a specific output format that isn't highlighted in original problem. 
    list.sort()
    list.reverse()

    if (isinstance(list[0], str)):
        list.append(list[0])
        list.pop(0) 

    return list
```

Yet when I run it as a standard function, it runs this error. I don't understand why `isinstance()` is running a index out of range here.

Comment: is that the full program?? where are you calling the function? can you write how you are using the function?

Comment: It is not `isinstance()` that throws the exception. It is the `list[0]` expression, because `list` is *empty*.

Comment: Full function. I am simply passing the function a array through test cases. The problem is a entry level problem in codewars.com called 'find duplicates'

Comment: @Johnathan well what you are doing in the function call is fine but if you can look at the shell you are actually overwriting a list.
the duplication looks fine but what are you trying to do with the sting poping? would you mind to elaborate what is your purpose at the end of the duplicate function?

Comment: @JA Thanks, I get why the shell was running it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing of all is never name a variable `list,string,dict etc..`

the list  variable is empty so only this error

It happens here:

```
list = []
for i in array:
    if (array.count(i) > 1): 
        if (list.count(i) < 1):
            list.append(i)
        else: pass
```

As per your input to the function there is no duplicates so the first `if` fails so there is no value in `list`

You are trying to access a uncreated index

i.e.)

```
las=[]
las[0]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**In your program:**

```
if (isinstance(list[0], str)):
    list.append(list[0])
    list.pop(0)
```

you are checking `list[0]` which is a empty string so error is thrown

As per your program

you are only storing duplicate values to `list` variable since your input does not contain any duplicate value it shows this error

You could try this

**modification:**

```
if (list) and(isinstance(list[0], str)):
    list.append(list[0])
    list.pop(0)
```

It checks is list is available then tries to get it's first element

Comment: Can you elaborate why or point to a reference that explains this? When I run it without if (isinstance(list[0], str)):
    list.append(list[0])
    list.pop(0), it works fine.

Comment: runs [4] no problems detected on both.

Comment: wait will add more details

Comment: @Johnathan you are welcome but never name variable as `list,string,dict etc` because it will shadow  the actual method

Answer (score 0):

```
def duplicates(array):
    list = []
    for i in array:
        if (array.count(i) > 1):
            if (list.count(i) < 1):
                list.append(i)
            else:
                pass

    # has nothing to do with problem statement. Test cases are requiring a  specific output format that isn't highlighted in original problem.
    list.sort()
    list.reverse()

    if len(list) > 0:
         if (isinstance(list[0], str)):
             list.append(list[0])
             list.pop(0)

    return list

duplicates([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the first if statement :

`if (array.count(i) > 1):`

In your test case, this condition is never met. So you'll never append anything to `list`.

You should check that your list is not empty before, like this :

```
if (len(list) > 0 and isinstance(list[0], str)):
        list.append(list[0])
        list.pop(0)
```

But since your function seems to detect duplicate in a list, everything looks fine there